# How to skip any strings values from an dataframe column - Pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which a column must accept only decimal fields, what can I do to
skip or delete all of the rows that values in this columns are strings?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and show some code for what you've already tried, and what went wrong with your attempts, so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: Can you please share your sample dataframe, expected output dataframe, and as per my prev comment, your MRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the column to a numeric type by using `pandas.to_numeric` with errors coerce parameter, which converts all the non-numeric fields to `numpy.nan`. Then you can select rows without `numpy.nan` at the certain column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # make a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col_str': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', "crdtar"]})
    df["col_str"] = pd.to_numeric(df["col_str"], errors="coerce")
    sel_df = df[~df["col_str"].isnull()]
    print(sel_df)
```

Result:

```
   col_str
0      1.0
1      2.0
2      3.0
3      4.0
4      5.0
```